# Module not found during SBT compile

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, sbt, snowplow

I'm trying to build to build a snowplow kinesis app from here -

https://github.com/DigdeepDigital/snowplow/tree/kinesis-redshift-dripfeed/4-storage/kinesis-redshift-sink

I have cloned the branch by doing

```
$ git clone -b kinesis-redshift-dripfeed git://github.com/DigdeepDigital/snowplow.git
```

not

```
$ git clone git://github.com/snowplow/snowplow.git
```

as the build instructions state.

but when I run

```
$ cd 4-storage/kinesis-redshift-sink
$ sbt compile
```

I get an error -

> module not found:
>   com.snowplowanalytics#snowplow-hadoop-shred_2.10;0.4.0

I'm not familiar enough with this to be able to troubleshoot easily. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I get the same error. You'd have to contact somebody at snplow.com and ask them why their Maven repo doesn't have the artifacts that project needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/snowplow-user/DK85l5Zw1U8).

For posterity, the solution is:

```
$ cd 3-enrich/scala-hadoop-shred
$ sbt publishLocal
```

This builds the version of the scala-hadoop-shred jar specific to that branch and puts it in the ~/.ivy2 directory.